# Expecting messages that do not change application state in RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rspec

In testing literature, you hear not to assert on outgoing messages unless they change the state of something else. In other words, query messages that don't affect state are stubbed with `allow().with().and_return()`.

The problem I have with this method is that when all of these allows happen in the before block, when a method's parameters change, every test will fail. This is because the `allow().with()` block will not be triggered.

Consider this example:

```
describe('#some_endpoint') do
  let(:another_class) { instance_double(AnotherClass) }
  let(:presenter) { instance_double(Presenter) }

  before do
    allow(another_class).to receive(:presenter).with(some_args).and_return(presenter)
  end

  it 'assigns the correct presenter' do
    get :some_endpoint
    expect(assigns(:presenter)).to eq(presenter)
  end

  it 'responds with ok status' do
    get :some_endpoint
    expect(subject).to have_http_status(:ok)
  end

  it 'does something else' do
    .....
  end
end
```

This example follows the testing literature and does not assert on `another_class.presenter` because that is a query message. If, however, the expected arguments to the presenter, `some_args` changes in the code, all tests will fail. This is much easier to debug if only the `assigns the correct presenter` test fails, which is the actual failure in the case of an argument change; because the presenter that is returned is not the correct presenter. The following tests would accomplish that goal:

```
describe('#some_endpoint') do
  let(:another_class) { instance_double(AnotherClass) }
  let(:presenter) { instance_double(Presenter) }

  before do
    allow(another_class).to receive(:presenter).and_return(presenter)
  end

  it 'assigns the correct presenter' do
    get :some_endpoint
    expect(another_class).to have_received(presenter).with(some_args)
    expect(assigns(:presenter)).to eq(presenter)
  end

  it 'responds with ok status' do
    get :some_endpoint
    expect(subject).to have_http_status(:ok)
  end

  it 'does something else' do
    .....
  end
end
```

What are the disadvantages of testing this way? I only see advantages. If this is the case, why is it that the testing community suggests not testing query messages?

Comment: it is opinion-based and will be closed Noah

Comment: I'm trying to get other people's opinions. Is there a better place to ask this, then?